# :not found bash script, mysql dump

Tags: bash, unix, mysql

Help me please. When I execute .sh

```
mysqldump -ulogin-ppass --all-databases > dumps/dbs.sql;
```

I get error message

/home/b/script.sh: 1: /home/b/script.sh:
: not found

but command create file successfully!

As I understand when the sign ; is in the end, error message occurs. Without it  error : Directory nonexistent

Comment: Show your script content.

Comment: DIR=`date +%F_%H-%M`; mysqldump -ulogin -ppass --all-databases > dumps/mysql/$DIR/dbs.sql;

Comment: Please put new info into the question using "edit", not in the comments. Much harder for people to find information in comments.

Comment: It is complaining about line 1 of `/home/b/script.sh`. What is on line 1?

Comment: Is your script in DOS/Windows format (\r\n line endings) instead of unix (just \n)? You can use `cat -vet scriptname` to check (look for "^M$" at the ends of lines, instead of just "$").

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 DIR=$(date +%F_%H-%M)
 mkdir $DIR
 mysqldump -uusername -ppassword --all-databases > $DIR/dbs.sql
```

Comment: cannot create dumps/mysql/2015-12-13_00-11
/dbs.sql: Directory nonexistent

Comment: You need to create dumps/mysql/ folder first

Comment: I created. The problem is in semicolon

Comment: You don't have to use semicolon in script or command line.
Semicolon is required inside mysql shell.